# Optimizing matrix vectorization within a cell

Tags: matlab, cell, vectorization

I am currently writing a function that converts a cell array into sparse block matrix.

I did achieve my purpose and now I am trying to optimize the code, but I just cannot seem to find a way to speed up the vectorization of matrices within the cell.

Currently, I have set the input as a column cell vector like the following:

```
Input = cell(Blocks,1);
```

Each cell inside the input has variously sized matrices.

To vectorize the matrices inside the cell, I am currently using this code:

```
V = cellfun(@(x) x(:), Input, 'un', 0);
```

But my profiler keeps on telling me that this part of my code takes up a lot of time.

I did try to change this into a for loop:

```
Blks = size(Input,1);

V = cell(Blks,1);

for i = 1:Blks
    V{i} = Input{i}(:);
end
```

However, this only makes my code run slower than my previous code.

Is there another alternative way to speed up the vectorization process of the matrices within the cell?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

I wanted to add another information.

After I calculate V, I concatenate all the cells and turn them into a single vector Val by doing so:

```
Val = cat(1,V{:});
```

At first I tried using cell2mat instead of cat, but it turns out that cat is much faster.

If there is a way to calculate Val without going through calculating V, it would be much better :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the most efficient way, but I get a 50% improvement on run time:

```
% Time the two versions of the algorythm
t1 = timeit(@test1)
t2 = timeit(@test2)
disp([num2str((t1 - t2) / t1 * 100) ' % improvement'])

% Prepare the same input for the two functions, 5 cells
% with random sized matrices
Input = cell(1,5);
for k = 1 : 5
    Input(k) = {randn(abs(round(randn(1,2).*10)))};
end

% Check if the results are the same
disp(all(test1(Input) == test2(Input)))



function Val = test1(varargin)
    if isempty(varargin)
    % Prepare three cells for testing
        Input(1) = {randn(5,4)};
        Input(2) = {randn(8,3)};
        Input(3) = {randn(2,4)};
    else
        Input = varargin{1};
    end

    % Your current method
    V = cellfun(@(x) x(:), Input, 'un', 0);
    Val = cat(1,V{:});
end


function Val = test2(varargin)
    if isempty(varargin)
    % Prepare three cells for testing
        Input(1) = {randn(5,4)};
        Input(2) = {randn(8,3)};
        Input(3) = {randn(2,4)};
    else
        Input = varargin{1};
    end

    % Store size of all matrices in the cells. I am adding 
    % a 0 at the beginning of the array for the indexing of
    % the following cycle
    s = [0 , cellfun(@numel, Input)];

    % Pre-allocate variable
    Val = zeros(sum(s) , 1);
    % Fill variable
    for k = 1:numel(Input)
        Val(sum(s(1:k))+1 : sum(s(1:k+1)) ) = Input{k}(:);
    end
end
```

I get:

> t1 =
>
> 1.2515e-04
>
> t2 =
>
> 6.0825e-05
>
> 51.3965 % improvement

---

Edit: Corrected an indexing error in test2

---

Edit: Corrected a second indexing error in test2 and modified it to be testable

Comment: I tried your solution, but it seems to give out wrong answers.

In the for loop, Val equation should be

    Val( sum(s(1:k))+1 : sum(s(1:k+1)) ) = Input{k}(:);

I tried the revised solution, but it does not seem to speed up the code :(

Comment: You are right, I modified the indexing and also the function to be testable. I do get the same results from the two versions now, and I still get a consistend 50-70% improvement! Maybe it is setup-dependent?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by 'setup-dependent.' Do you mean by the MATLAB version? My MATLAB version is 2016b, and it would be quite surprising to find out that this could cause the speed difference. By the way, this is just out of curiosity but could there be a speed difference due to the arrangement of vectors? That is, whether if the vector is column or row vector? My testing code handles the input variable as a column cell vector, and I was just wondering if this could affect the speed.

Comment: By setup-dependent I mean differe CPU, RAM, etc. I am running 2016b as well, so that is not the reason of the difference, and I don't think rows vs columns should change the timing, but you are welcome to try!.